# REST API Web/Lists SharePoint Online vs. On-Premise - different responses?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-server, web

I'm currently working on a client application for iOS which retrieves documents libraries from a remote SharePoint 2013. To support SharePoint Online as well as On-Premise installations i got a test environment for both cases. While playing around with the REST API Web/List-endpoint i noticed some differences regarding the amount of data returned by the services.
In my special case i need to retrieve files of a document library by working with the "Files" metadata json dictionary.

Calling the service at SharePoint Online i get this:

```
"d": {
    "results": [{
        ...
        "Files": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://myown.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')/Files"
            }
        }
        ...
    }]
}
```

Calling the endpoint at SharePoint On-Premise the "Files"-Dictionary is missing completely. But I need this information for retrieving all attached files.

Does this have something to do with a settings which can be done in the central administration? Thanks for any advice

Update: I found an alternative way to retrieve the files using the "Items"-Dictionary with the corresponding URI. Solved my concrete problem with a roundabout way but unfortunately i didn't find an answer to the original question..

Comment: Are you having relevant permissions or you have to code elevated priviledges?

Comment: Yes, i'm site collection administrator in both cases

Comment: Anyone around having a clue? Thanks...